# Handling the upgrades to dynamoDB table post adding the LSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table in my microservice, which I choose to add an LSI to the table after few days of creating it.
Once I redeploy the microservice, all the records in the table got wiped off because of the addition of the LSI into the table.
Is there any smart way to keep the records backed up post the re-deployment? AWS datalake can be used to export and import data to and from s3. But this does not make sure the tables have the data in there during the time of deployment.

Comment: Adding a LSI requires creating a new table, because they can only be defined on table creation. If you're using CloudFormation, you can check out the `UpdateReplacePolicy`, it may be helpful to also retain the old table, so you can later copy the data over - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html)

Comment: I use terraform for deployment. But I don't see similar stuff in terraform though